# Strange Automatic Transmission Issue

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, corolla

I'm not sure if this is cause to worry or not, but there is a bit of back story to this as well;

I drive a 2006 Toyota Corolla with an automatic transmission. About 3 years ago, a line in my transmission had degraded and leaked all the fluid out. I drove the car for about 2 hours without realizing this, until finally getting to my destination and having the car not get in gear. The repair was completed successfully, and the shop claimed there was no damage. Lethal bullet dodged.

Since then, I have not noticed any strange transmission issues, except for in the past few months. Occasionally, a part of my commute for work requires me to drive on a road with quite a steep downhill bit, tractor-trailer warning signs and all.

The hill down has a 45mph speed limit. I will notice from time to time that while braking down the hill, my car stays at a higher gear, or will even shift up to another gear. This causes the car and pedals to vibrate quite a bit. Once I'm at the bottom of the hill, the speed becomes 55 again, and usually once I get back on the accelerator, the transmission will shift down properly.

Is this something to be concerned with? I only experience it on hills like this, but that example was the most clear.

Comment: Have you checked the current state of your transmission fluid?

Comment: Not recently, but the car did pass inspection two weeks ago. I figure if the transmission isn't up to par it wouldn't pass, though maybe I don't know all the ins and outs of inspection.

Comment: Safety and emissions inspections in Utah don't bother checking the state of the transmission; after all, a car that doesn't go anywhere is usually pretty safe. I don't know the rules in NY, though. 

It's a pretty quick thing to check for a quick lube station if you don't know how to do it yourself - but do ask them to show you the before and after state of the fluid if they add/change any. (keeps them honest... :p )

Comment: When the original transmission issue occurred, I learned where to check. Having a close call like that is a good reminder to check it as the years go by, but I'll check things out on a day when it isn't raining!

Comment: And it doesn't look like NY cares about transmissions either, according to [this page](https://dmv.ny.gov/brochure/new-york-state-vehicle-safetyemissions-inspection-program)

Comment: If you have to go down hill, I'd assume you also have to go uphill as well? Do you see any problems during the ascents?

Comment: None that i can discern, no.

Comment: @PeteCon it finally stopped raining, and i checked my transmission fluid. Looks good, was a pinkish color and a bit above the hot marker.